# Fit image into GridView

Tags: android, image, xamarin, gridview

I want to fit my 4 gridview images like the image shown here:

[image: Desired layout]

But in my current layout, the images doesn't fit perfectly with the gridview.
 Anyone can help?

Current layout:

[image: Current layout]

**Mainmenu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/sublayout_Toolbar" />
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.4" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.6">
                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/mainMenu_GridView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:numColumns="2"   
                    android:listSelector="@null"
                    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/light_blue" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**GridAdapter.MainMenu**

```
namespace Dental_IT.Droid.Adapters
{
    class GridAdapter_MainMenu : BaseAdapter
    {
        private readonly Context context;
        private int numRows = 2;
        private int[] items;

        public GridAdapter_MainMenu(Context c, int[] i)
        {
            context = c;
            items = i;
            }

            public override int Count
            {
                get { return items.Length; }
            }

            public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
            {
                return null;
            }

            public override long GetItemId(int position)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                ImageButton button;

                if (convertView == null)
                {
                    button = new ImageButton(context);

                    //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
                    //button = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.grid_mainmenu, null);
                    // ImageView imgView = button.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.grid_image);

                    button.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
                    button.SetMinimumHeight(Main_Menu.GRID_HEIGHT / numRows);
                    button.SetImageResource(items[position]);

                    switch (position)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            button.Click += delegate
                            {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(Select_Hospital));
                                context.StartActivity(intent);
                            };
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            button.Click += delegate
                            {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(My_Appointments));
                                context.StartActivity(intent);
                            };
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            button.Click += delegate
                            {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(Treatment_Information));
                                context.StartActivity(intent);
                            };
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            button.Click += delegate
                            {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(Search));
                                context.StartActivity(intent);
                            };
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    button = (ImageButton)convertView;
                }

                return button;
            }
        }
    }
```

**MainMenu.cs**

```
 private readonly int[] buttonTexts =
    {
        Resource.Drawable.ic_request_appt,
        Resource.Drawable.ic_my_appt,
        Resource.Drawable.ic_treatment_info,
        Resource.Drawable.ic_search
    };
```

Comment: Please click on the link to view the images.

Comment: post gridview single item layout file.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have to write this as an answer, can't comment yet. I would assume that one of the parent items is passing down some sort of padding, so I would suggest explicitly setting padding to 0 for the items in the grid view. If that doesn't work, it might be inherited margin parameters. Otherwise it might be that the images in the drawables folder aren't the correct size and are thus being rescaled to best fit. It seems like to me that they might be getting scaled up a bit anyway. I hope this helps a little. Let me know if you have any further questions about my comment/answer.